# Do Loop to output new column SAS

Tags: sas, macros, do-loops

I have dataset that looks like this:

```
ID      Date        Calendar_Yr 
1     07/04/2023      2023          
1     09/01/2023      2023
1     02/01/2024      2024
1     04/04/2024      2024
```

I would like to have a dataset that looks like this:

```
ID      Date           Calendar_Yr   
1     07/04/2023       CY 2023    
1     09/01/2023       CY 2023   
1     02/01/2024       CY 2024
1     04/04/2024       CY 2024
```

Can put the column CY_Year into a macro variable and then try a do loop around a "if/then Column Name = "CY &CY_Year."

Comment: Is the existing variable Calendar_Yr variable numeric or character?  If it is numeric you will need to make a NEW variable name to make a character variable. If it is already character is it defined long enough to hold the new longer strings?

Comment: You don't need to loop manualy, SAS will do that in a data step automatically. See https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001290590.htm

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for looping to create your new variable.

```
data want;
   set have;
   length CY_Year $7 ;
   CY_Year = catx(' ','YR',Calendar_Yr);
run;
```

In general you use macro code to generate code, but there is no code generation needed for this problem.